# Creating a lock for a console application

Tags: c#, locking, console-application

I have a console application which will be initiated by different batch files set up windows task scheduler. I would like to queue these commands or have some sort of a lock mechanism in my application that would have all the commands waiting on a queue, so that only one command runs at a time. I was thinking about doing some sort of a file lock, but i cant get my head wrapped around to how would it work for queuing commands. I just need some sort of direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For inter-process synchronization, you may use a [`Mutex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/01985e8f) instance representing a named system mutex.

```
// Generate your own random GUID for the mutex name.
string mutexName = "afa7ab33-3817-48a4-aecb-005d9db945d4";

using (Mutex m = new Mutex(false, mutexName))
{
    // Block until the mutex is acquired.
    // Only a single thread/process may acquire the mutex at any time.
    m.WaitOne();

    try
    {
        // Perform processing here.
    }
    finally
    {
        // Release the mutex so that other threads/processes may proceed.
        m.ReleaseMutex();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look for `Semaphore` object.

```
_resultLock = new Semaphore(1, 1, "GlobalSemaphoreName");
if (!_resultLock.WaitOne(1000, false))  
{
    //  timeout expired
}
else
{
    //  lock is acquired, you can do your stuff
}
```

You can always put your timeout to Infinite, but it is practical to get control over the program flow from time to time and be able to abort gracefully.